# Extracting youtube chanel links with rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

Hi I am trying to extract video URLs from single youtube channel. I need my code to take channel link such as https://www.youtube.com/c/mattymatheson/videos?view=0&sort=dd&flow=grid and return vector containing video URLs. I have tried:
'''

```
url %>%
read_html() %>%
html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="video-title"]') %>%
html_attr("href")
```

'''
But it returns character(0)

Comment: Why are you scraping it? YouTube provides API's which will you help get this information.

Comment: You are right, but its part of my task to complete it using r script.